# Elastix(Asterisk) Slow to repsond on incoming PSTN line

Tags: asterisk, pbx, pstn

I setup a PBX with asterisk and Elastix as a web GUI. I have all incoming calls set to ring to a ring group of our office personnel in a ringall format. The only issue is the time for Asterisk to pickup and pass the phone call to the VOIP phones to ring from our PSTN lines. It takes about 5 rings to start ringing our VOIP phones in the office and it goes to our carrier's voicemail before we get a change to even pickup the phone. I'm not sure why Asterisk is taking so long to pass on the call. We are using Siemens Gigaset DE380 IP R phones with a Digium TD410 card.

Comment: Not a solution to the core problem, but you may want to have your carrier disable their voicemail feature if possible and use the voicemail functionality Asterisk provides (all my users prefer it - particularly as it forwards voicemails to their email accounts so they can check them on the road)

Comment: pastebin your dialplan.

Comment: @TomO'Connor http://pastebin.com/67URhXxv

Comment: Please pastebin the console output when receiving a call as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be asterisk is expecting caller-id but not receiving it? Just a guess as most caller-id on PSTN lines should happen somewhere around the first ring.

Comment: If this was the case, how could it be prevented? How to get Asterisk to avoid the delay? I am not interested in caller-id in this case.

Comment: To answer myself: see https://community.freepbx.org/t/dahdi-inbound-callerid-and-delays-solved/34477/19. You need to change options in /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf